# Graphics2D get String's dimension before drawing

Tags: java, string, user-interface, label, graphics2d

In my program, I'm drawing a String like this:

```
graphics2D.drawString(string, x, y);
```

However, in order to determine the x and y, I would like to know the dimension (height and width) which this string is going have. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [FontMetrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) class for that. You can get the `FontMetrics` to use from the `Graphics` object, and then use the `stringWidth` and `getHeight` methods to get the size.

```
FontMetrics fm   = graphics2D.getFontMetrics();
int stringWidth  = fm.stringWidth(string);
int stringHeight = fm.getHeight();
```

Comment: One thing to take care of: the `x, y` you specify in the drawString points to the baseline of the first character, not to (e.g.) the top-left of the string. To take that into account use `fm.getAscent()`: "The font ascent is the  distance from the font's baseline to the top of most alphanumeric characters."